# Delphi Berlin EObjectiveC with message 'ObjectiveC class CTCallCenter could not be found

Tags: ios, objective-c, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

im using Delphi 10.1 Berlin

Just running the PhoneDialer sample on an IOS Phone

Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Mobile Snippets\PhoneDialer

the app is crashing on startup
if i run in debug mode im getting this error

---

Debugger Exception Notification

Project PhoneDialer raised exception class EObjectiveC with message 'ObjectiveC class CTCallCenter could not be found'.

---

it looks like its happening in the
**FMX.PhoneDialer.iOS** unit

```
constructor TCocoaPhoneDialerService.Create;
begin
  FCallCenter := TCTCallCenter.Create; // <<<----- blowing up here
  FCallCenter.retain;
  FCallCenter.setCallEventHandler(DoChangeCallState);
end;
```

does anyone have any suggestions?
if you can get the sample to work can you include the code needed to make it happen :)

As a side note - Delphi 10.0 Seattle running the same sample seems to works fine

Comment: try to look at Tools \ Options \ Environment Options \ SDK Manager and compare to Delphi 10.0 Seattle

Comment: @Passella Can you get the sample to work in Berlin? i have done a quick compare in the SDK manager they are both using iPhoneOS9.3.sdk the berlin one does have a few extra include paths "usr/lib/clang/7.0.2" and "usr/lib/clang/7.3.0"

Comment: sorry I do not have Berlin here.I thought it might be that

Answer (score 0):

This workaround came from Sergey Krasilnikov 
you can see it here https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15128 if you have a login
i have not tried it yet to confirm if it works or not

Copy iOSapi.CoreTelephony.pas from
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\source\rtl\ios
to your project folder

Modify it in the following way:

```
implementation

uses
  Posix.Dlfcn;

var
  CoreTelephonyModule: THandle;

const
  CoreTelephonyFwk: string =     '/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony';
```

and

```
initialization
  CoreTelephonyModule := dlopen(MarshaledAString(libCoreTelephony), RTLD_LAZY);

finalization
  dlclose(CoreTelephonyModule);

end.
```

Build the project again